# Can't use dependency injection in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, google-drive-api, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6. I have a service provider class called DriveServiceProvider. This class has all the dependencies that are needed to connect with google drive.The following is my Service Provider

```
      <?php

     use Hypweb\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveAdapter;
     use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
     use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


     class DriveServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
     {

       public function register(){


       }

       public function boot()

       {

       Storage::extend('google',function( $app,$config){

        $client=new \Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
        $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
        $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
        $service=new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $adapter=new GoogleDriveAdapter($service,$config['folderId']);
        return new FileSystem($adapter);
       });



     }
 }
```

I want to pass this service provider to a controller, the following is my controller

```
     <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cloud;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use App\Providers\DriveServiceProvider;
  use Hypweb\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveAdapter;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
  use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;


  class uploadFileController extends Controller{

   public $filesystem;

   //Attempting Dependency Injection
   public function __construct(DriveServiceProvider $filesystem)  {


    $this->filesystem=$filesystem;

    }

   public function createFolder(){

    $directoryName='Demo';

    $this->filesystem->createDir($directoryName);

     //return $$filesystem->folder_id;

    }

   public function deleteFolder($id){

     $this->filesystem->delete();

     }






   }
```

When i run the script , it's throwing the fllowing error

```
  Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
  Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class     
  Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
```

What's wrong with my code ? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier approach to do Google Drive implementation in Laravel install.

```
composer require nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive
```

In `filesystems.php` include your google config.

```
    'google' => [
        'driver' => 'google',
        'clientId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'clientSecret' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'refreshToken' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'),
        'folderId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'),
    ],
```

Now you should be able to get your files like so.

```
Storage::disk('google')->get('yourfile');
```

This is inspired by this following [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/mehranhadidi/38e38b80e3d533650ed2b94a0f95f7f1).

Comment: is there a way , i can make a dependency injection without the error i mentioned ? should i use binding ?

Comment: With the storage facade instead of using dependency injection, you should use the facade. Often dependency injection is used for testing, if that is the case, you should use storage fakes https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#storage-fake and secondly why do you need to do it dependency injected?

Comment: The package which i am using in this project is not fully capable of what i want to accomplish.i am adding some extra classes to the package. So every time i need to make a call to drive API , i don't want  to hard code config values such as client secret , client id (etc) in every controller class i make, Instead if i can use dependency injection , i can call all the dependencies easy.That's what i am trying to achieve.I am already using the same package you suggested.

Comment: In this solution you are not reusing anything, it is defined in the config?

Comment: It is defined in config. For example. i need a class for uploads only. i use the flysystem package.so, to authenticate  connection to drive, i need client id, client secret, refresh token. i need these parameters globally, so that i can call them any where in my package, that's why i am using the service provider.

Comment: and how is my solution not global?

Comment: I tried to access methods in the GoogleDriverAdapter package , from which i am unable to access many methods, that's the reason i am trying to do something else.The service provider i listed above can not serve my purpose.I found another way. made a new service provider , and everything is working as expected. thank you for your time @mrhn